# Docker Image Build Error mysqli_sql_exception

Tags: docker, dockerfile

so i am making a docker file to run a simple website hosted on local host , when i run the docker image my php shows Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Permission denied in /var/www/html/f5.php:68 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/f5.php(68): mysqli->__construct() #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/f5.php on line 68

i am pasting my docker file below , i have tried all avalaible AI chat still getting no solution
Thank you

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04
#Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update
&& DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive" apt-get install -y apache2 php libapache2-mod-php php-mysql mysql-server

#Install mysqli extension
RUN apt-get install -y php-mysqli

#Copy PHP files
COPY f5.php /var/www/html/ RUN chown www-data:www-data /var/www/html/f5.php RUN chmod 644 /var/www/html/f5.php

#Copy SQL file
COPY lab1.sql /var/www/html/

#Configure MySQL
RUN service mysql start
&& sleep 5
&& mysql -u root < /var/www/html/lab1.sql
&& mysql -u root -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON . TO 'root'@'localhost';"
&& mysql -u root -e "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
&& service mysql stop

#Configure Apache
RUN a2enmod rewrite RUN sed -i 's/DirectoryIndex index.html/DirectoryIndex f5.php/' /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf

#Remove default index.html
RUN rm /var/www/html/index.html

#Start Apache and MySQL services
CMD service mysql start && apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND
```

I tried all the solutions. I was expecting the docker to be build perfectly.